# How to much time take a request in javascript axios?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, request

I've an application where I get the data from an API, every things is working fine, but I want to know how much time a request take in times, so I've used the **interceptors** from **axios** and I get the time  in milleseconds, **BUT** the problem is that the time I get `request-duration` is after the request respond which is not useful I want to know the time before or at calling the webservice, the thing make it hard for me is that the method I call is located in another file:
**Request.js**

```js
export const getRequest = async (url, baseURL, headers) => {
  const HTTP = axios.create({
    baseURL,
    headers,
  });
  HTTP.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    config.headers["request-startTime"] = new Date().getTime();
    return config;
  });
  HTTP.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    const startTime = response.config.headers["request-startTime"];
    response.headers["request-duration"] = currentTime - startTime;
    return response;
  });
  return HTTP.get(url);
};
```

**Users.vue**

```js
async getUsers() {
  try {
    let url = `/users`;
    let baseUrl = `baseURL`;
    let headers = {};
    const responseUsers = await getRequest(url,baseUrl,headers); 
    console.log(responseJobTasks.headers["request-duration"]); //show how much milleseconds here
    if (responseJobTasks.status === 200) {
      const { data } = responseJobTasks;
      this.users = data;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: "I want to know the time before or at calling the webservice" hmm, why would you need to know request duration in advance? And how do you expect it to actually work? This is like future prediction.

Comment: Because I need to show user progress of a Javascript request

Comment: it's usually helpful to visualize something is happening in the background.

Comment: Axios allows you to track upload/download progress that might be useful for showing progress bars for longer request, plz check the docs. But nothing like you could have certain time in advance. There is no way to predict network and server conditions.

Comment: Yes it's possible; I found something on [dev.to](https://dev.to/tqbit/how-to-monitor-the-progress-of-a-javascript-fetch-request-and-cancel-it-on-demand-107f)  blog but its implemented by using fetch not axios!

Comment: It is not predicting request time. It shows download progress which is not supported out of the box in `fetch API` that is why all the hustle. For axios (implemented via `XMLHttpRequest`)  there is `onDownloadProgress` handler that allows you to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can know it simply by taking the timestamp of the before and after:

```
const before = Date.now();
const responseUsers = await getRequest(url,baseUrl,headers); 
const after = Date.now();
const duration = after-before;
```

Another option is the [User Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/User_Timing_API), but it is overkill for timing a single request.

Comment: it's the same I need to wait till the request end!

Comment: @XMehdi01 What do you mean? After `await getRequest()`, the request will have ended before the next line executes.

Comment: What I want is to monitor the progress of a Javascript request?

Comment: @XMehdi01 How do you expect to know the time a request takes without performing the request? This is like asking how many times you need to flip a coin to get heads: you don't know until you flip the coin enough times.